# Add combo-box item through method - c#

Tags: c#, methods, combobox

I need to add an item to a combo-box from other class,
this is the method in the class that has the combo-box:

```
public partial class NMAP : Form
{
    public void Add_ip(string ip)
    {
         IP_box.Items.Add(ip);
    }
}
```

The code where I'm calling the function:

```
public class MainGame
{
    NMAP n = new NMAP();
    n.Add_ip("0.0.0.0");
}
```

With nothing special, just adding an item through other class.

Comment: You are adding items to a combo inside a new instance of the form NMAP. You are not adding items to the currently displayed form of type NMAP. The new instance isn't ever shown and you can't see the result of your efforts. If you want to see them add _n.Show();_ after the add.

Comment: Pass the current instance of `NMAP` to the `MainGame` class (using its constructor, maybe). Using this reference, the items that `Add_ip` adds to the ComboBox will be visible. If `NMAP` doesn't still exist, then create a new instance of the Form (as you're doing now), add the items and `Show()` the Form.